# Invalid entry in my search bar in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a search bar, it works well so far. I would like to improve my search bar.

When I enter a name which is not in my listing I will wish to stay on my page index with all the recordings.

For example: If I enter `leonard` as name

[image]

I have a page empty...

[image]

Is it possible to stay on my page index with my recordings ?

Here's my relevant code:

```
public function index(Request $req)
{
   if ($req->has('search') && !empty($req->search)) {
        $validated = $req->validate([
        'search' => 'alpha', 
        ]);

        $students = Student::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $validated['search'] . '%')->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->paginate(5);
        $students->appends($req->only('search'));
        return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'));
        }

        $students = Student::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'));
}
```

Comment: There's no need to put "question:" in your title. We know you have a question; that's why you're posting a question on Stack Overflow.